# What files can be deleted to decrease local profile size

Tags: windows-7, profile, local

I am deploying windows 7 through altiris and I am noticing that the profile sizes under C:\users\username are about 200MB.  Is there any way to trim the fat? I already deleted the temp files out of the appdata folder but I am sure more can go.
Anyone got any thoughts on what can go? I am now at 117MB

Comment: What, supposedly, is taking up the space?

Comment: yes, could you provide a dump of directory sizes? If you're pre-provisioning things like firefox profiles, photoshop, gimp, or msoffice, that's probably not out of the ordinary

Comment: Yeah thats what I had on there office cs3 and a few other apps.
I am trying to eliminate installing apps with wise setup capture through altiris but I wanted keep common apps on the image.
Thanks for you comments.

Comment: The microsoft folder under app data is 90 meg on its own.

Comment: Try running ByteCount to see what the folder sizes are...think it's at http://www.xs4all.nl/~hneel/software.htm

Comment: I used tree size pro (old school) to see which folders they were it was the App data folder and the microsoft folder within that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users are running Outlook in cached mode, the OST file (offline storage) is placed in the profile, that could take up some space and is easy to get rid of (it will just regenerate, if I remember correctly).

However, for Win7 deployments I would really urge you to have a look at USMT4.0, the newest version of the user state migration tool. It lets you maintain the user profiles on local disk while doing a new installation of windows (through some dark magic I think), which eliminates the whole user profile problem altogether.

Comment: But USMT is if you want to migrate your data from say an XP machine.
How would you use this to manage the default user profile on a new machine? Thanks

Comment: You can also use it to keep the User Profile while reinstalling Windows on the same machine, to eliminate the need to copy it out somewhere while doing the install. I might have misinterpreted your question. If you want to shed a bit more light on how your Win7 rollout is done, there might be someone here able to help you better.